# How to get Modules to work in VS2019 16.8?

Tags: c++, module, visual-studio-2019

I'm trying to convert my program to modules. I'm using MSVS 19 Community Edition version 16.8 (also tried with MSVS19CE Version 16.9.01 Preview)

Each .ixx IDF I write compiles fine when compiled indiviually, (with "import"'s and its usage commented out),

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: myCare, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Scanning sources for module dependencies...
1>Compiling...
1>DB.ixx
1>Compiling...
1>HS.ixx
1>pch.cpp
========== Build: 1 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

But when I introduce the commented out imports, suddenly VS can't find the modules it just previously compiled beautifully.

```
Build started...
1>------ Build started: Project: myCare, Configuration: Debug x64 ------
1>Scanning sources for module dependencies...
1>Compiling...
1>HS.ixx             <<<<-----  Compiled without errors
1>Compiling...
...
1>ComplexComboBox.ixx
1>D:\Dev\myCare\Modules\ComplexComboBox.ixx(289,1): error C2230: could not find module 'HS'
1>D:\Dev\myCare\Modules\ComplexComboBox.ixx(289,1): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation
1>INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR in 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.28.29333\bin\HostX86\x64\CL.exe'
1>    Please choose the Technical Support command on the Visual C++
1>    Help menu, or open the Technical Support help file for more information
1>Done building project "myCare.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

```
error C2230: could not find module 'HS'
error C2230: could not find module 'Aui'
error C2230: could not find module 'Ctrl.ListCtrl'
```

Any hints? Every module has the structure like this (and has the file extension .ixx)

```
module;

#include "Defines.h"
#include <any>
#include <bitset>

...

export module HS;

namespace HS
{
    export enum class Comms { None = 0, Port = 1, Timeout = 2, Authority = 3, Security = 4 };
    
    export auto CommsAuthority(const AuthorityType newValue)->void;
    export auto CommsAuthority(void)->AuthorityType;
    
    (Not everything in here is exported)
    ...
}

module :private;

auto HS::CommsAuthority(const AuthorityType newValue)->void
{
    ...
}
auto HS::CommsAuthority(void)->AuthorityType
{
    ...
}

...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be a bug with the way visual studio currently handles modules imported by other modules. Essentially when each module compiles it creates a `<module_file_name>.ixx.ifc` file. This is detected perfectly fine when the module is imported into a cpp file but not when importing to a module. removing the `.ixx` from the filename will import correctly whether importing to another module or a cpp file though.

I solved this in 1 of my own projects through the project properties(the required options are only available in the preview version of visual studio at the moment though).

So you first need to set `Module File name` to `$(IntDir)%(Filename).ifc` in `C/C++->Output Files`

Then set `Additional BMI Directories` to `$(IntDir)` in `C/C++->General`.

Visual studio puts all the intermediate module stuff in the intermediate directory by default but if you'd rather have all your intermediate module things in a separate folder you can set `Module Dependencies File` in `C/C++->Advanced` to wherever you want and then update the `$(IntDir)` bits above to the new location.

Comment: Thanks. That worked. BTW the C/C++ options are available in the released version of MSVS 16.8, you no longer need to use the 16.8 Preview version.